# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: Cannot create field 'semesters' in element

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

DataBase in MongoDB :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("610144532aa8eb54745f7501"),
    "courses" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("61014585d71b225516d0116f"),
            "course" : "MBA",
            "semesters" : [
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("61014587d71b225516d01174"),
                    "sem" : 1,
                    "subjects" : [ ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Schema :

```
const Subject = mongoose.Schema({
    subject : String,
    units : [UnitSchema]
});
```

Code that i am using to add a document in subjects array

```
app.get('/insertSubject', async function(req, res)
{
    const subject = new Subject({
        subject : req.body.subject
    })
    await Padhlo.updateOne(
        {"courses.course":req.body.course , "courses.semesters.sem":parseInt(req.body.semester)},
        {$addToSet : {"courses.semesters.$.subjects":subject}},
        function(err)
        {
            if(!err)
            {
                res.status(200).send("OK");
            }
            else
            {
                res.status(404).send(err);
            }
        }
        )
});
```

Error :

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: Cannot create field 'semesters' in element
```

I want to add a document inside the subjects array but it is giving this error the updated db should look like this :

```
 {
    "_id" : ObjectId("610144532aa8eb54745f7501"),
    "courses" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("61014585d71b225516d0116f"),
            "course" : "MBA",
            "semesters" : [
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("61014587d71b225516d01174"),
                    "sem" : 1,
                    "subjects" : [
                        subject : "BCA",//added new field according to Schema 
                        units : [ ]
                   ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Please help me and tell me where i am going wrong I am new and noob to mongoDB The version that i am using MongoDB : 5.0.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer [MongoDB The all positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/)

> The all positional operator $[] indicates that the update operator should modify all elements in the specified array field.

Try this query

```
await Padhlo.updateOne(
    { "courses.course": req.body.course , "courses.semesters.sem": parseInt(req.body.semester) },
    { "$addToSet" : { "courses.$[].semesters.$[].subjects": subject } }
)
```